# Azure Service Bus Brokered Message Security

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I'm using Brokered Messaging (Topics/Subscriptions) in Azure Service Bus and I'm curious how (or whether) the communication is secured using SSL.

I'm sending and receiving messages using the connection string:

```
var connectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString");
var Client = TopicClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, "TestTopic");
Client.Send(new BrokeredMessage());
```

Is that message secure when it is sent?

Answer (score 3):

Yes and no.  The communication to and from your client to the Azure server is encrypted if using TLS (SSL).  Once that communication is complete and the data is passed along to the server process, it's no longer secure (it's behind the Azure firewall, etc. etc. but no longer encrypted).

Brokered messaging does not have a message-level security option like relayed messaging (WCF option) so only transport-layer security is used--which means it's only protected while in that transport layer.

Comment: To add to what Peter mentions, any data that you want to encrypt end-to-end you should do so yourself in the message body. Service Bus needs to read the message properties to do routing/filtering but the body of a messages is transferred as-is so you can perform any kind of encryption on that at the application layer and it will not affect the messaging layer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are using SSL by default.  It might depend on your connectionstring, but I tested (and verified with Fiddler) with the following connection string and can say it is transport level encrypted:
Endpoint=sb://myns.servicebus.windows.net;SharedSecretIssuer=owner;SharedSecretValue=mykey
cheers

Comment: Great thanks, I noticed the same thing using Fiddler. Do you know if there's any Azure documentation that explains this?

Comment: I searched for it (wanted to add it to this reply), but didn't find it, to be honest.  With the WCF binding for the service bus relay, you can easily configure it, based on the binding, didn't find it for the messaging features.